# how to capture user_type asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session, authentication

I have login page with users having 3 user typs. from login im capturig user id and password. but i want to check user_type field and depending on that redirect to diferent pages after login. please advice me

Comment: This is depend how you want to do ? You want to get usetype from DB then

Comment: @dotnetstep : yes i want to check the user type for the user id which user entering when login to system. and if the User_Type "admin" he should redirected to Admin panel page

Comment: I have already provided answer. Please check that and let me know it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this if you want to read from DB.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT User_Type FROM [User] WHERE User_Id =@userid and User_Password=@password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Convert.ToInt32(txtUserName.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
    reader.Read();
    string userType = reader.GetString(0);
        Session["USER_ID"] = txtUserName.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Login Failed");
    }
```

Comment: is there any posisbility add css style attributes in side if else loops on asp.net. Ex: if user type Admin header css color need to change , please advice

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using the User_Type returned from the database:

```
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        Session["USER_ID"] = txtUserName.Text;

        switch((string)dt.Rows[0]["User_Type"])
        { 
            case "UserType1":
                Response.Redirect("UserType1Dashboard.aspx");
                break;
            case "UserType1":
                Response.Redirect("UserType2Dashboard.aspx");
                break;
            case "UserType1":
                Response.Redirect("UserType3Dashboard.aspx");
                break;
            default:
                Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Login Failed");
    }
```